# Grep/Awk for Value Between

Tags: linux, awk, grep, data

So I have a text file with lines like this:

```
http://sg.ovies.m/.ss/ (Status: 200) [Size: 128]
http://sg.mo.v/.dev/ (Status: 200) [Size: 12328]
http://som.b/.hal/ (Status: 200) [Size: 1238]
http://m.cb/.ho/ (Status: 200) [Size: 0]
http://sm.jo/.hK/ (Status: 200) [Size: 0]`
```

I would like to only grep the lines where Size is between 1 and 100.

So the output would be:

```
http://sg.ovies.m/.ss/ (Status: 200) [Size: 128]
http://sg.mo.v/.dev/ (Status: 200) [Size: 12328]
http://som.b/.hal/ (Status: 200) [Size: 1238]
```

How can it be done using grep or awk?

Comment: Is the trailing backtick on the last line a typo?

Comment: You say you want between 1 and 100, but in your example output all sizes are larger than 100.  I've written an answer based on the 1 to 100 rule and ignored your example output.

Comment: Line 2 of your sample output appears to have a typo in the size (12328 vs likely 1238)

Answer (score 1):

Awk makes this easy:

```
awk '{size=$5; sub(/]/, "", size); size=size+0; if (size <= 100 && size >= 1) {print $0 } }' file_to_read.txt
```

Writing this in a more friendly way:

```
awk '{
    # create a new variable "size".
    # items are separated by spaces, we need the 5th item
    size=$5;

    # remove the trailing "]"
    sub(/]/, "",  size);

    # make sure size is an int
    size=size+0;

    # Choose rows with seize between 1 and 100
    if (size <= 100 && size >= 1) {
        # print the whole line
        print
    }

    }'  file_to_read.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `:` character occurs in only 3 places in your input, we can use that as field separator, then extract the number for comparison via substring (with accounting for leading space):

```
awk -F':' '{size=substr( $NF,2,length($NF)-2 ); if((size>=1)&&(size<=100)) print }' input.txt
```

Note that you've asked for "Size: is between 1 and 100." However your sample output reads as "Size greater than 1". If that is the case, then if statement can be reduced to `if(size > 1) print`

Answer (score -1):

The following pattern should do it:

```
grep -E 'Size: (?:100|[1-9]|[0-9]{2})]' test
```

I tells grep to use extended RegEx syntax (`-E`) and tries to match either `100` or a value from 0 to 99 following `Size:`

Comment: I just tested this and it included the `Size: 0` rows

Comment: That is true, but is such a value actually possible?

Comment: It's in the question.  When someone gives example data in a question, its best to test your answer on that example data.  And yes.  0 byte HTTP responses are possible.

Comment: I have updated the pattern, it now excludes 0.